# save a multidimensional array with different sub-array length python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I tried to save a multidimensional array with different sub-array length into a text file by python.
My code is:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.arange(5)*0.1
c = np.arange(3)*10
v = [list(a),list(b),list(c)]
v = np.array(v)
v = v.T
np.savetxt("file.dat",v)
```

The result shows:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

I think that it is because the lengths of the sub-arrays(lists) are not same.

Would you please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you,

Isaac

Comment: The problem is that `a`, `b`, and `c` don't have the same `len`, so v is a "jagged" list, so when you call `np.array(v)` it's making an array of objects, each of those objects being a python list. Numpy doesn't support jagged arrays, really. Essentially, you can work with an array of lists, or an array of arrays, but the dtype has to be `object`, which pretty much defeats the purpose of `numpy`. Just use Python lists.

Comment: Thank you juanpa.arrivillaga: I would like to save a, b, c as columns in the same file. Would you please suggest any way to do it? v.T does not support list.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `v` before the `savetxt`:

```
In [34]: v
Out[34]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0.0, 0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004, 0.40000000000000002],
       [0, 10, 20]], dtype=object)

In [36]: v.shape
Out[36]: (3,)
```

It's a 1d, 3 element array that contains your 3 arrays.  `.T` does nothing.  `savetxt` is designed to save a 2d table.  You may need to experiment with creating arrays from components like this.  The fact that they differ in length is important.

At best `savetxt` can write 3 lists to the file:

```
In [39]: np.savetxt('test.txt',v,fmt='%s')
In [40]: cat test.txt
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0.0, 0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004, 0.40000000000000002]
[0, 10, 20]
```

What output were you expecting?

==============

`zip_longest` can create 'columns'.  The default fill is `None`.  I can fill with an empty string, but then I have to use the `%s` fmt.

```
In [50]: for v in itertools.zip_longest(a,b,c,fillvalue=''):
    ...:     print('%5s, %5s. %5s'%tuple(v))

    0,   0.0.     0
    1,   0.1.    10
    2,   0.2.    20
    3,   0.3.      
    4,   0.4.      
    5,      .      
    6,      .      
    7,      .      
    8,      .      
    9,      .
```

Or with an intermediate array:

```
In [51]: arr=np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(a,b,c,fillvalue='')))
In [52]: arr
Out[52]: 
array([['0', '0.0', '0'],
       ['1', '0.1', '10'],
       ['2', '0.2', '20'],
       ['3', '0.3', ''],
       ['4', '0.4', ''],
       ['5', '', ''],
       ['6', '', ''],
       ['7', '', ''],
       ['8', '', ''],
       ['9', '', '']], 
      dtype='<U32')
In [53]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr, fmt='%5s',delimiter=',')
In [54]: cat test.txt
    0,  0.0,    0
    1,  0.1,   10
    2,  0.2,   20
    3,  0.3,     
    4,  0.4,     
    5,     ,     
    6,     ,     
    7,     ,     
    8,     ,     
    9,     ,
```

Comment: The reason I did v.T is to the 3 arrays as columns, Thank you for answers.

Comment: i've added examples using `itertools.zip_longest' (PY3) to form 'padded' columns.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj. It really helps.